# Defining derivatives and integrals for hyperoperations > 2

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

Derivatives and Integrals are continuous generalizations of the Forward Difference and Summation additive operators respectively. We can do the same with multiplication and get multiplicative calculus with the geometric derivative (continuous forward ratio) and the product integral (continuous indefinite product). I propose a bigger generalization for all hyperoperations > 2.

First we define the n-th Hyperoperation as
$$H_{n}(a,b)=\begin{cases}b+1&\text{if }n=0\\a&\text{if }n=1\text{ and }b=0\\0&\text{if }n=2\text{ and }b=0\\1&\text{if }n\geq3\text{ and }b=0\\H_{n-1}(a,H_{n}(a,b-1)) &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

$H_{-n}(a,b)$ being the corresponding inverse function (substarction, division, rooting, etc.) and $_{n}\mathrm{H}^{c}_{i=b}\,a_{i}$ the recursive use of the n-th hyperoperation over $a_{i}$.

Using these concepts, we then define the n-th ''Hyperderivative'' operator as
$$_{n}D_{x}\,f(x)=\lim_{h\to{0}}H_{-n+1}(H_{-n}(f(x+h),f(x)),h)$$
and the n-th ''Hyperintegral'' operator as
$$_{n}J_{x}\,f(x)=\lim_{\Delta{x}\to{0}}H_{n+1}(_{n}\mathrm{H}_{i}\,f(x_{i}),\Delta{x})$$
Could this be used as a good definition? In which areas of maths would these continuous hyperoperations be useful?

I appreciate any feedback.

Comment: This is all ill-defined. Maybe you don't know but $H(a,b)$ is only defined on the naturals. So the limit $H(a,\Delta x)$ is meaningless just as $H(f(x+h),f(x))$ is meaningless.

Answer (score 2):

While I do not know if this is what you are trying to get at, there do exist "accepted" versions of calculus for the hyperoperations. In fact, the topic of non-newtonian calculus studies how to make a calculus out of any binary operation with "nice enough" properties. I suggest reading Grossman and Katz's Non-Newtonian Calculus, available for free on google books. There is a chapter on multiplicative calculus, as well as other types, but also on the arbitrary "*-calculus" which is the general version and might apply to what you are doing here.

The calculi concerning hyperoperations would be generated (technical term described in the book) using the function $\exp\circ \exp\circ ...\circ \exp$. They would be the next step up after multiplicative calculus.

There are many other more modern references to check out, such as [this one](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022247X07003824). Good luck!